# Computing the stable manifold for a fixed point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, manifolds

> Compute the stable manifold of $(0,0)$ for the system
>   $$\dot{x}=x-y^3$$
>   $$\dot{y}=-y$$

Here in my proposed solution

---

My first step isn't necessary for the solution. Although, it is helpful in seeing whether or not the x-axis and y-axis are stable.

The Jacobian is $J(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} \\ \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -3y^2 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Therefore, $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{dx}{dt} \\ \frac{dy}{dt}  \end{pmatrix}=J(x_0,y_0)\begin{pmatrix} x-x_0 \\ y-y_0  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ -y \end{pmatrix}$.

So, the x-axis is unstable while the y-axis is stable.

---

To compute the stable manifold, we need to apply the stable manifold theorem. By the definition of $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y}{x-y^3}$$

Therefore,

$$ydx + (x-y^3)dy=0$$

We can now apply the theory of integrating factors which states that $M(x,y)dx
+N(x,y)dy= 0$. We are given that $M(x,y)=y$ and $N(x,y)=x-y^3$. If we follow the first example in [this pdf](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/sen/Math_235/Lectures/lec_5s.pdf), we see that the equations are exact since

$$M_y(x,y)=1=N_x(x,y)$$

So, we will therefore find a general solution such that $f(x,y)=C$. Hence,

$$f = \int Mdx + g(y)= \int ydx + g(y)= xy + g(y)$$

But, we know that

$$f_y=N=x-y^3=x+g'(y)$$

which implies that

$$g'(y)=-y^3$$

and so

$$g(y) = \int -y^3dy =\frac{-y^4}{4}+C$$

Hence,

$$f(x,y)=xy+\frac{-y^4}{4}=C$$

is the general solution. To avoid singularities in the orbits of $y(x)$ which pass through $(0,0)$, we should set $C=0$. Then,

$$xy=\frac{y^4}{4}$$
$$4x=y^3$$
$$\sqrt[3]{4x}=y$$

Therefore, $y(x)=\sqrt[3]{4x}$ is the stable manifold. I'm not sure if there is a shorter approach to compute the stable manifold. The solution inside [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696608/understanding-explicit-computation-of-a-stable-manifold-in-mathbbr2) doesn't appear to work for this problem.

Is this approach correct? Please let me know if there are any better alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

A simpler way is to realize that on the stable manifold the asymptotic values of $x$ and $y$ are 0

$$
\lim_{t\to +\infty} x(t) = \lim_{t\to +\infty} y(t) = 0
$$

With this in mind, note that the solution for $y$ is fairly trivial

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} = -y ~~\Rightarrow~~~ y(t) = e^{-t} \tag{1}
$$

which makes the solution for $x$ even simpler

$$
\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} = x - e^{-3t} ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ x(t) = \frac{1}{4}e^{-3t} + \cancelto{0}{\strut c} e^{t} = \frac{1}{4}e^{-3t} \tag{2}
$$

And from here it you can conclude that the equation of the manifold is

$$
x = \frac{1}{4}(e^{-t})^3 = \frac{1}{4}y^3 \tag{3}
$$

Here's a simple sketch that shows this solution, just to make sure everything checks out. The curve (3) is the solid black line

[image]